# SMS Text Message when loggin g in

Tags: login, sms

Currently my users are setup to use the Salesforce Authenticator as their 2FA method.  However, I would instead like them to have a text sent to their phone.  They will find this easier.  How do I switch to having someone receive an SMS message instead of using the Salesforce Authenticator?

Comment: Not possible out of the box, see FAQ at https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352937&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it.
You need to disable your 2FA then enable SMS verification method.

**Step 1: Disable 2FA**
Gear icon --> Setup --> Security --> Session Settings --> Session Security Levels.
Right-hand Side multi-select column Select Two Factor Authentication and click Remove button.
[image: Disable 2FA]

**Step 2: Enable SMS Verification**
Gear icon --> Setup --> Security --> Session Settings --> **Enable** the SMS method of identity verification.
[image: Enable SMS Verification]

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I already have the SMS option checked.  How does someone who has 2FA with the authenticator set now use SMS instead.

Comment: You can disable it from the profile level & permission set level

Comment: Identity Verification is not the same thing as authentication via another factor, unfortunately.

Comment: I mentioned the identity verification because the setting was disabled in my org.